# Powershell appending text from csv file to text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy csv file contents and append to a text file.
The copying and appending works, but the appended format is weird.

This is the command I use:

Get-Content -Path myfile1.csv | Select-object -skip 1 | Out-File mynewfile.txt -Append

The appended text looks like this when opened in notepad:

```
1 0 2 3 8 9, 1, A B C, P 2
```

instead of

```
102389,1,ABC,P2
```

There's a space between every character.
Just renaming the .csv to .txt didn't help.

Comment: Check the encoding on the two files.  If one is ASCII and the other is UTF-8,  that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Add-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet:

> The Add-Content cmdlet appends content to a specified item or file. You can specify the content by typing the content in the command or by specifying an object that contains the content.

```ps
Get-Content -Path myfile1.csv | Select-object -skip 1 | Add-Content mynewfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 5.1, the default encoding for `Out-File` is **unicode** (UTF16-LE), whereas in PowerShell 7.x the default encoding is **utf8NoBOM**.
Apparently, your input file is encoded differently, like with ASCII or UTF-8. and when adding UTF16-LE text to it, the result is what you experience.

Out-File has an `-Encoding` parameter, so you can fix your code by appending `-Encoding default` OR by using `Add-Content` instead of `Out-File`.

<sup>Encoding `Default` is the encoding that corresponds to the system's active code page (usually ANSI)

Add-Content also has a parameter `-Encoding`. In PowerShell 5.1 it defaults to `Default`. In PowerShell 7.x the default encoding is `utf8NoBOM`.</sup>